# std::set of std::weak_ptr insert and remove

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers

In my main application, I have an `std::set<std::shared_ptr<Object>>`. I also want to create a secondary set of `std::set<std::weak_ptr<Object>>` because I don't want to increment the reference count but I also want to avoid calling bad memory locations by using a lock. Unfortunately, I cannot define a `std::set` with `std::weak_ptr`s inside. Having done so, the compiler complains with some errors in the insert and remove methods.

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
class Test{
private:
    int x ;
public:
    Test(int x){
        this->x = x;
    }
    int getx(){
        return x;
    }
};
int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<Test> t = std::make_shared<Test>(10);
    std::weak_ptr<Test> ref = std::weak_ptr<Test>(t);
    std::set<std::weak_ptr<Test>> weakrefs;
    weakrefs.insert(ref);//compiler error
    weakrefs.erase(ref);//compiler error
}
```

But when I use `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Test>>`, I'm allowed to push back and pop back. But I would like similar functionality to `std::set`.

Comment: Is `std::unordered_set` an option?

Comment: Yes @JohnDing I actually didn't consider that. Does it change the functionality of the container in any way other than ...ordering? I imagine by ordering it's keeping a unique objectt?

Comment: I don't know what function do you need. However if you only want to use the property of a set (insert, find, delete). I think unordered set is a better option. Most of the time it has much better performace than ordered ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a set of `weak_ptr`s, you need `std::owner_less<>`, a special comparison operator:

```
std::set<std::weak_ptr<Test>, std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<Test>>> weakrefs;
```

This comparison operator uses the administrative region to look up the smart pointers, not the pointers to the object that they point to. This is necessary because the object can be deleted while the smart pointers are still in the `std::set`.

You should actually also use `std::owner_less` for a set of `shared_ptr`s.

Comment: Edit: I changed the code and it does work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I use std::vector< std::weak_ptr< Test>>, I'm allowed to push
>   back and pop back. But I would like similar functionality to std::set.

`std::set` is an ordered container. It means that when you insert something, the data structure needs some comparisons to find its right place (inside the internal tree). Because of this, as @j6t has mentioned, you need to introduce a compare operator while defining the set. This is not the case for the `std::vector` because for the `std::vector` you keep the elements one after another, without any comparisons.